# error reading settings archive file: <ISRootSettings

Tags: ios

```
2016-04-18 14:19:16.383 walk[428:103037] *** error reading settings archive file: <ISRootSettings: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3584E782-85B3-4FB9-89DC-492CC5840FE5/Documents/com.welink.walk.settings/ISRootSettings_10.plist> 
2016-04-18 14:19:16.673 walk[428:103037] CLTilesManagerClient: initialize, sSharedTilesManagerClient
2016-04-18 14:19:16.673 walk[428:103037] CLTilesManagerClient: init
2016-04-18 14:19:16.673 walk[428:103037] CLTilesManagerClient: reconnecting, 0x1612b0420
2016-04-18 14:19:16.674 walk[428:103159] CLTilesManagerClient: XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID!
2016-04-18 14:19:16.693 walk[428:103037] Please remove uses of SCRCException!
libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception
(lldb)
```

Comment: Have you figured this out?

Comment: Same error, any solutions?

Comment: There really is not a question in the IP, however, this is not a rare issue. My app uses PhotoKit. The dev system is Xcode 9.0.1 and iOS 11/Swift4. The error:

*** error reading settings archive file: <ISRootSettings:....settings/ISRootSettings_10.plist>
Occurs inside segue between an AssetGridView and an AssetView, after the user selects image not in my code, but in Apple's. Occurs in Sim & actual devices. Look at plist file path, you can see that the plist file does not exist. Fortunately, this error does not cause any issue in the App's function. Just more annoying noise in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Able to workaround by including `kUTTypeImage` to the `mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String, kUTTypeLivePhoto as String]`.